# check if the cell of a table has a certain color

Tags: javascript, html

the cells of the table get for a short moment a red color . the cells are selected by random numbers.

when a cell has a red color then the user shall click the cell.

if he clicks the cell when the cell is still red then he get a point.

that is the idea. but it not works. when i click the cell nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      td{font-size:40px; padding:4px 10px;}
   </style>
   <script>    
      var blinkColors = new Array('red' );
      var zw= new Array();
      var blinkColor = 0;
      var iterator = 0;
      var hit=0;

       for (var i = 0 ;i<10;i++){
          zw[i]=Math.floor((Math.random() *8) + 1);
       }

       var myBlink = setInterval(function() {
         doBlink();
       }, 400);

       function doBlink() {    
          var blinkCell = document.getElementById('blinker' +zw[iterator] );    
          blinkCell.style.backgroundColor = blinkColors[blinkColor];
          blinkColor++;   
          if (blinkColor == blinkColors.length+1) {
             blinkColor = 0;
             blinkCell.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
             iterator++;

             if (iterator == zw.length) {
             alert("You hit. " + hit);
             clearInterval(myBlink);
          } else {
            doBlink(zw[iterator]);
          }    
      }

      function hitColor(blink){
         if (document.getElementById('blink').style.backgroundColor=="red")
         hit++;
     }    
</script>
</head>
<body>   
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td id="blinker0"onclick="melden(blinker6")> A </td><td id="blinker1"> B </td><td id = "blinker2"> C </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td id="blinker3"onclick="melden(blinker6")> D </td><td id="blinker4"> E </td><td id = "blinker5"> F </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td id="blinker6" onclick="melden(blinker6)" > G </td><td id="blinker7"> H </td><td id = "blinker8"> I </td>
  </tr>    
 </table>
 <br>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need a space before "onclick". Also consider setting the class in the onclick handler instead of modifiying the color directly.

Comment: <td id="blinker0"onclick="melden(blinker6")> A </td><td id="blinker1"> B </td><td id = "blinker2"> C </td>

Comment: i made a mistake in the code i sent. the name of the function i changed fom german to english. please, before you test change hitcolor(blink)  to melden(blink).

Comment: fix the code so it contains no syntax errors before you ask your question. Totaler Schrott!

Answer (score 0):

Pull the second if block out of the first one:

```
  if (blinkColor == blinkColors.length+1) {
    blinkColor = 0;
    blinkCell.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    iterator++;
  }

  if (iterator == zw.length) {
    alert("You hit. " + hit);
    clearInterval(myBlink);
  } else {
      doBlink(zw[iterator]);
  }
```

Comment: can you take a look at my answer?